# Prove that there is no surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Prove that there is no surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Attempt:
If possible let $\phi(x) :\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Q} $ be an onto homomorphism,
then it is easy to prove that $\phi$ fixes $\mathbb{Z}$, if we determine where $x$ goes to then we end up determining the homomophism $\phi$.

Say $x\to \frac{p}{q}$, then any element in the image of the homomorphism can be written as $a_0+a_1\frac{p}{q}+a_2(\frac{p}{q})^2+ \dots+a_n(\frac{p}{q})^n$.

I am unable to proceed further

Comment: Hint: look at the denominators

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone give an example of an ideal $I \subset R= \Bbb{Z}[x_1,...x_n]$ with $R /I \cong \Bbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102128/can-someone-give-an-example-of-an-ideal-i-subset-r-bbbzx-1-x-n-with)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from where you left of:

So every element in the image is of the form
$$\frac{q^n a_0 + q^{n-1} a_1 p + \dots + a_n p^n}{q^n}.$$
So, elements of ${\mathbb Q}$ that have a prime factor in their denominator that does not divide $q$, are not in the image.

Comment: thank for the answer.... so consider $\frac{1}{r}$, such that (q,r) = 1.Now we can deduce that $\frac{q^n}{r} = integer$, from the above assumption, which is absurd.